# Azure CLI 'login' command not found when the application is bundled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, azure-cli

I am working on a Python GUI that lists all container image tags within a given repository stored in Azure Container Registry. It appears to me that the Azure SDK for Python include a 'RegistriesOperations' class but without the option to list image tags. I have found a way to access this list through python Azure-CLI and it works, it is not pretty, but it works. However, I would like to distribute the application as a Windows EXE generated by PyInstaller. It seems to work as intended as the application window shows, but whenever the application invokes CLI commands it crashes with the following error message:

az: 'login' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'.

I get a similar error with the 'acr' command whenever I omit login.

```py
cli = get_default_cli()
cli.invoke(['login', '--service-principal','--username', USERNAME,'--password', PASSWORD,'--tenant', TENANT])
cli.invoke(['acr', 'repository', 'list', '-n', REGISTRY])
```

I have added the entire azure and knack libraries as hiddenimports. Used different versions of PyInstaller: 3.1.1 and 3.5. Run PyInstaller on Win10 and Win7 through docker Wine. None of it works, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first authenticate silently

`az login --service-principal -u http://sample-cli-login -p Test1234 --tenant xxxx`

Then you can use

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli

cli = get_default_cli()
cli.invoke(['acr', 'repository', 'list', '-n', REGISTRY])
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! However, it did not solve the issue completely. I have implemented your suggestion this way:

        cmd = 'az login --service-principal -u {} -p {} --tenant {}'.format(AZCLI_USERNAME, AZCLI_PASSWORD, AZCLI_TENANT)
        subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

        self._cli = get_default_cli()
        self._cli.invoke(['acr', 'repository', 'list', '-n', REGISTRY])

But it returns the same error whenever the acr repository command is invoked:
az: 'acr' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'.

Comment: Are you able to run the command directly through command line? For example: `az acr repository list -n REGISTRY`?

Comment: It is possible that you are missing a couple of extensions:
`az extension add --name aks-preview`

Comment: Yes it works just fine if I run the commands directly through command line. And it works fine if I run the commands through the python azure-cli library. But whenever the python library is baked into an EXE with PyInstaller it stops working and I can't find a way to debug it.